# How do I get eclipse ADT to show on my device for debugging?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt, device

I have my project set up to test and my device and my device has the correct driver installed for USB debugging but when I go to `Run > Run Configurations...` and choose my device and then click run, it just loads up the normal emulator on my PC.

How do I make it appear on my tablet? Am I missing a step? I've followed everyone's steps but they don't mention anything else other than what I've done.

Comment: are u aiming to debug on ur real device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have correct driver installed for USB debugging , You can do debugging/ run via

run-> run configurations->click Target tab-> select always prompt to pick device

Comment: Then what should happen? my device is just at the home screen from start up. should the test app automatically come on?

Comment: connect ur device via usb then run ur app that will be shown prompt box from there u can see ur device name then give ok.

Comment: Hmm I think I have a problem with the OEM driver. I need to get that sorted.